# What is the most efficient way of checking for specific python modules and installing the ones not found?

Tags: python, import, module

I would like to check if a list of third party python modules are installed before my script proceeds. For example, here is a list of modules that my script would need in order to run:

```
modulesList = ['numpy', 'PIL', 'boto']
```

I want the script to check if each of those modules are installed and if not, automatically install them. Is there a way to do that without having to write what I have below every single time for each item in the list?

```
try:
    import foo
except ImportError:
    if extraModules == True:
        os.system(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'scripts','pip install foo'))
        import foo
    else:
        print 'ERROR: The script cannot run without the foo module installed.\n'
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: If the module is not installed, do you want to install them? If they are installed, do you want to import them? This is a list of string names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should do the job:

```
import pip

pkgs = ['numpy', 'pil', 'boto']
for package in pkgs:
    try:
        import package
    except ImportError, e:
        pip.main(['install', package])
```

Comment: Do you know if the script changes the configuration of pip or any other modules? I have been getting the following error since running that script: ImportError: cannot import name shares_memory

Comment: What IDE are you using?
From what I've heard, that is a part of numpy thats not being properly installed. You can try to reinstall it from your terminal with `pip install -I numpy --force-reinstall`

Comment: I am using WindIDE. I was able to fix it, but I am wondering if there is a way to use that solution without having to fix things afterwards.